Samourai Wallet missing funds
I apologize if this has been asked and answered... This past weekend I found out about the shutdown of Samourai Wallet. I had some BTC in there that is now gone.
I'm well aware of the fact that Samourai balances show up as 0.000 because of the servers being gone, but this is more: There was a withdrawal on 4/29 that emptied the account.
I have recovered the Wallet to Sparrow, but shows a balance of 0.
I have read posts saying that the xpub is now compromised by the Feds...Can someone help me with finding out where this transaction went? Much appreciated!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QxX_2uPiROKyiNPHo3YzLyjUogCEYDTM

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R9V1D8wGDpzX2vuFYWmCRLKPamPQ5Cl3


There was a withdrawal on 4/29 that emptied the account.

You can check the transaction at any blockchain explorer for example, Blockchair

Can someone help me with finding out where this transaction went?

It went to address bc1qel94nj4vu2aedmmy5ffrpaxs4c007cwv4e96ka but it would likely be extremely difficult, perhaps impossible, to find out what person or organisation created that addess.
Even if you could, any hope of recovering money without expensive legal processes - perhaps in foreign countries - might be almost non-existent.
For the equivalent of $1800, about 5 hours of a lawyers time, I doubt there is any point in persuing this.

Related:

Is it possible to track stolen Bitcoin after exchange
How can I confirm to whom the bitcoin address I sent a payment too?

